# Can we achieve all features which are pay to use in botium box through botium core

Tags: bots, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

I'm planning to understand botium core with sample github projects
given currently i've referred the alexa smapi git project and updating my project .

My question is ??Can I achieve all paid features of botium box through coding in botium core or only a said amount of features is allowed thorough coding in botium core in any given IDE like vs code or eclipse.

Comment: Botium Core is published with MIT licenses (https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), of course you can build your own code on top of it. If you have any amendments to Botium Core it would be nice to bringt them back to the Github project, of course ...

Comment: Okay , Can i use all features of botium box through coding in botium core

Comment: There is no "magic" in Botium Box, only several years of hard development work ...